# A question on a solution of an inhomogeneous heat equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I am now working on the following PDE equation (Evan's PDE textbook Section 2.5 No.14)
\begin{align}
u_{t}-\Delta u + cu=f \ \ & on \ \ \mathbb{R}^n\times (0,\infty) \\
u=g \ \ & on \ \ \mathbb{R}^n\times \{0\},
\end{align}
where $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions on the domains above. Then the Fourier transform with respect to spacial variables yields 
\begin{align}
\hat{u}_{t}+|\xi|^2\hat{u} + c\hat{u}=\hat{f} \ \ & on \ \ \hat{\mathbb{R}}^n\times (0,\infty) \\
\hat{u}=\hat{g} \ \ & on \ \ \hat{\mathbb{R}}^n\times \{0\}. 
\end{align}
Then this ODE can be solved as 
$$
\hat{u}_{t}=e^{-t(c+|\xi|^2)}\hat{g}+\int_{0}^{t}e^{(s-t)(c+|\xi|^2)}\hat{f}ds,
$$
and therefore we get 
$$
u(x,t)=e^{-ct}(\phi_{H}*g)(x,t)+\int_{0}^{t}e^{(s-t)(c+|\xi|^2)}\hat{f}ds. 
$$
I wonder if this is what the author expect readers to derive. This seems quite complicated. Can it be reduced to be an simpler form than this?

Answer (score 2):

Being in the same department as Evans, I actually *do* know what the author expects from the reader. Craig Evans always says this when referring to some linear PDE: "My colleagues would use the Fourier transform, but they're wrong."

He might be joking usually, but in this case there is a nicer way. He would instead advise the following: Consider the change of variables $v(x,t) = e^{ct} u(x,t)$. I think you can take it from there.